# How can I get value Model class Object to ArrayList as String?

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am storing id of selected value from Spinner, id is stored successfully but I don't know how can I see String values in Spinner,currently I am getting Object values in spinner list.

I am getting object value but I want to display String which I stored in Database.

Database

```
ArrayList<Bankers> getBankers(){
    ArrayList<Bankers> bankersList = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select id,bankers from "+Table_Name_Bankers,null);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bankers_Table_Column1));
                String bankers = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bankers_Table_Column3));
                Bankers bankersModel = new Bankers(id,bankers);
                bankersList.add(bankersModel);
            }
        cursor.close();
    return bankersList;
}
```

Getting List

```
 ArrayList<Bankers> bankersListSpinner = databaseHelper.getBankers();
    ArrayAdapter<Bankers> lead_bank_spinner = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.spinner_item,bankersListSpinner);
    lead_bankers.setAdapter(lead_bank_spinner);
    lead_bankers.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            bankersModel = (Bankers)parent.getSelectedItem();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Getting Input

```
Bankers = bankersModel.getId();
```

Comment: Create a custom adapter , get your value and show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add this to your model class.

```
public String toString() {
    return bankers;
}
```

This will work for you.